# return serialized object (if it exists) otherwise return new instance?

Tags: java, class, object, instance

I want to get a serialized object by calling this method:

```
ArrayList<String> myArrayList = (ArrayList<String>) getSerializedObject(ArrayList.class, "arraylist.ser");
```

If the specified file (arraylist.ser) does not exist, or does not match the class I passed in, I want to return a new instance of that class.

```
private Object getSerializedObject(Class<?> c, String filename) {
    Object serObject = null;

        try {
            if (new File(filename).exists()) {
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
                Object tempObj = in.readObject();
                if (tempObj.getClass().equals(c)) {
                    System.out.println("Loading "+filename);
                    serObject = tempObj;
                }
                in.close();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        if (serObject != null) {
            return serObject;
        }
        else {
            // return new instance of Class c here
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method you are accepting `c` as input, which is some unknown type represented by a `Class<?>` object.  If the type represented by `c` has a `public` no-arg constructor, then you can create a new instance by calling:

```
try {
  // return c.newInstance(); -- DEPRECATED as of Java 9
  return c.getConstructor().newInstance();
} catch (Exception e) {
  // handle case of no such public, no-arg constructor
}
```

If it does not, then you will get an exception.  If you don't want to cross your fingers and guess and instead want to find out what constructors are accessible to you, the Reflection API will give you that information:

```
Constructor[] publicConstructors = c.getConstructors(); // may have .length == 0
for (Constructor ctor : publicConstructors) {
    // find the one you want
}
```

You can then inspect those objects to see what types of arguments are required for each.  When you find the constructor that you want, you can call `newInstance(Object ...)` on the `Constructor` object and pass the appropriate argument values.

Even with that information, however, you would need to somehow provide the appropriate values.  To solve this problem for "any class" is extremely difficult.  If you can restrict the values needed to zero or just a few specific values in a known order, then it becomes an easier problem to solve but it severely restricts the number or type of objects that your function is actually able to construct.

Also keep in mind these things:

Your method accepts any `Class<?>`, which includes `interface`s such as `List`.  Interfaces cannot be instantiated and have no constructor.  Your example is avoiding this edge case by using the concrete implementation `ArrayList`.

Constructors are not inherited in Java, so even if you verify that `c` is a subclass of `ArrayList` you cannot safely assume that `c` has the same constructor signatures as `ArrayList`.  (That is, unless it is really the same class: `ArrayList.class.equals(c)`.)

If this code is rewritten to say that it only deserializes `List` (or specifically `ArrayList`) instead of accepting any type then you can simply call the regular `ArrayList` constructor and save yourself some trouble.

But even if you do that, your code does NOT verify that the deserialized list is `ArrayList<String>`.  What comes out of the deserialization process will be `ArrayList<?>`, or `List<?>`, or perhaps something that is not even a `List` at all.  Assuming you were lucky enough that the file really does contain an `ArrayList`, the only way to know that the list "only contains `String`" is to verify each and every object in the list after you deserialize it.

Generics enforcement occurs at compile-time, and runtime deserialization doesn't verify the parameterized type is type-safe.  That's why the compiler will be emitting a warning about the unsafe cast:

```
Object out = getSerializedObject(ArrayList.class, "arraylist.ser");
ArrayList<?> unboundedList = (ArrayList<?>) out;  // verifies that 'out' is really an ArrayList
ArrayList<String> myArrayList =
   (ArrayList<String>) unboundedList; // UNSAFE!  Does not verify the list's contents!
```

Comment: Wow, this is good information. I have chosen your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using *reflection* you can create new instances of classes. I would point you to the package, but you are already using the `Class` class.

Of course, you probably will have to somehow chose a suitable constructor, if the default one does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the class already, and assuming all the classes have the same constructor signature, then you can do it with reflection.

This following is for a default no arguments constructor

```
Class<?>[] args = {};
Constructor<?> constructor = c.getConstructor(args);
Object inst = constructor.newInstance((Object[])args);
```